# How to fill NULL values with values from another table using UNION

Tags: sql, isql

I have to write a select statement that displays the orderId and Delivery address from one table but if there is no deliver address it should display the billing address of the customer. I'm unsure how to do this since UNION requires the same number of columns.

These are the two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER (
CustId number(4) NOT NULL,
CFirstName varchar2(30),
CSurname varchar2(30),
BillingAddr varchar2(30),
Gender varchar2(1),
PRIMARY KEY (CustId),
CONSTRAINT Check_CGender
CHECK (CGender IN ('M' , 'F'))
);

CREATE TABLE SHOPORDER (
OrdId number(4) NOT NULL,
DeliveryAddress varchar2(30),
CustId number(4),
SpId number(4),
PRIMARY KEY (OrdId),
CONSTRAINT FK_CustId
FOREIGN KEY (CustId) REFERENCES CUSTOMER,
CONSTRAINT FK_SpId
FOREIGN KEY (SpId) REFERENCES SALESPERSON
);
```

And this is the wording of the question:
Use a UNION clause to list each order id and address. The list must be in
ascending Order ID sequence. If the Shop Order delivery address is NULL,
then you must display the customer's billing address instead of the delivery address.

Any help would be much appriciated.

My current attempts lol

```
SELECT Ordid, DeliveryAddress
FROM SHOPORDER
UNION
SELECT NULL AS CustId, BillingAddr
FROM CUSTOMER;


SELECT S.OrdId, S.DeliveryAddress
FROM SHOPORDER S
UNION
SELECT S.OrdId, C.BillingAddr
FROM CUSTOMER C
INNER JOIN SHOPORDER S
ON C.CustId = S.CustId;

SELECT S.OrdId 
FROM SHOPORDER S
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER C
ON S.CustId = C.CustId;
(SELECT DeliveryAddress 
FROM SHOPORDER 
UNION 
SELECT BillingAddr 
FROM CUSTOMER );

SELECT OrdId, DeliveryAddress
FROM SHOPORDER
UNION
SELECT BillingAddr
FROM CUSTOMER;

SELECT OrdId, (SELECT DeliveryAddress
FROM SHOPORDER
UNION
SELECT BillingAddr
FROM CUSTOMER)
FROM SHOPORDER;
```

Comment: Have you tried writing a query yet yourself?  The best way to learn SQL is by using it.

Comment: why not just join shoporder on customer using CustId?

Comment: Try to perform a union between the orders with delivery address and the orders without delivery addresss.

Comment: left join with customer table and specify `if(DeliveryAddress not null, DeliveryAddress, BillingAddr)`

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `LEFT JOIN` and `COALESCE()`:

```
select so.OrdId, coalesce(so.DeliveryAddress, c.BillingAddr) as address
from shoporder so left join
     customer c
     on so.CustId = c.CustId;
```